# In React, what is the difference between declaring 'const' or 'let' between render() { return()} vs class extends component{render(){}}?

Tags: reactjs

What is the difference between declaring const inside of

```
class App extends Component {
  --- HERE ----
  render() {
```

Or in this form?

```
  render() {
    ---- HERE -----
    return (
```

And, how can I convert 'const' or 'let' that declared in the second format in the functional component? I do not see any render() part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't declare `const` or `let` in class outside of a function (improper syntax), but difference would be scope if it was possible.

```
class TestComponent extends Component {
  a = 10; // class scope

  render() {
    console.log(this.a) // access a from the class instance
    const b = 1337; // function scope
    return (
      <div>TEST</div>
    );
  }
}
```

For functional components, the entire component *is* the render function, which returns renderable JSX.

```
const TestComponent = props => {
  const { testProps } = props;
  return (
    <div>TEST</div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When declaring a `const` inside `render() {` it is only available in render method.

Example:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class Test extends React.Component {
  fromClass = "from class";

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.fromClass);
    // here there is no access to fromRender
  }

  render() {
    const fromRender = "from render";
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{fromRender}</div>
        <div>{this.fromClass}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit misty-frog-3mrmt]

Answer (score 0):

Declaring variables in render and outside render does have a huge difference in initialization. Imagine that you are using `componentWillMount()`(unSafe) lifeCycle method and the access to variables that you declared in render method is restricted or returns undefined. So only variables declared outside the render works.
If you declare a variable at the start of the component it executes at the beginning before render() starts working. I would recommend you to try console.log on variables declared in different methods and at different locations for your understanding.